# RSpec: Request specs execution time substantially slower due to lots of data being involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am building a series of APIs that operate on a pretty large amount of data. I have been using request specs in order to test them. For an average spec, I would need to have in the database around 20 to 30 records, which are connected to each other from a DB relational standpoint. The majority of the request specs require changing a small part of these records, as I need to test the APIs against many different possible scenarios.

And since I am mutating the data in most of the tests, I am supposed to recreate all those 20-30 records for each spec individually. As far as I am concerned, it is considered a best-practice to start with clean data for each test, unaltered by previous specs, so that each test is executed totally isolated from the others and proof against unwanted prior mutations.

My issue is that the execution time is highly affected (several seconds), as I always recreate the test data for each spec. I tried to two approaches:

- Use let! statements (cannot use simply let statements, as I always need the data to be stored in the db before each test)
- Use before(:all), in which I would define once the data for all tests and after each test was completed, recreate only the instance variables that were modified in that spec. Even though this speeds up the time seriously, I am afraid the tests correctness might be affected sharing the same state and not being isolated from each other.

What do you think would be the the best thing to do in my situation? Is there a way to obtain both a fast execution time and state integrity for the tests? Or should I pick one of the approaches I came up with above?

Comment: `before_all` is generally best avoided and setting up all your dependencies there is a recipe for test ordering issues and flapping tests.

Answer (score 1):

Performance of system-level tests is typically poor, compared to model tests. There's no easy answer, but you can make incremental improvement with a few tricks.

Test as much as possible in the model tests, and reduce the number of variations that are tested in the request tests.

Break down the model tests into tests of smaller pieces. You should not need 20-30 records for each model test. Just a small number should be sufficient.

You can load the database faster if you use sql directly vs. Ruby and ActiveRecord.